# Facebook Login through Graph API by not using FB Button

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm following the login instructions for Facebook's graph api found on this page:

[Facebook Login Quickstart](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/v2.1)

Simple question:  I do not want to use the FB button:

```
 <fb:login-button style"height=20" scope="public_profile,email, user_friends" onlogin="checkLoginState();">Login </fb:login-button>
```

I want to use the following:

```
<a href="#" onclick="fblogin()">Login  here</a>
```

What would be the correct way create a function for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the `FB.init()` , have that run when the page loads.

Then when the user clicks "Login Here", call `FB.Login()` or a custom function that calls `FB.Login()`.

The code they recommend using for `FB.Login()` is in that link you shared.